# Import Module System (Python Source Code Analysis)

Tags: python, import, module

These days I am looking into python-3.6.10 source code written in C. When we import a module like
`import a`,
it finally jumps to this function:

```
mod = _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs(interp->importlib,
                                    &PyId__find_and_load, abs_name,
                                    interp->import_func, NULL);
```

I find all code about this `PyId__find_and_load`, but find nothing. Can anybody tell me how this function works? And finally how does the import system in C work?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: so little knowledge out there about python c API, huh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_and_load function can be found in `Lib/importlib/*.py`.

Comment: I'd say that this * is _bootstrap